# What is the safest way to restart the svn server on Windows?

Tags: windows, svnserve

I fear that simple service restart may cause data corruption.

Does anyone know if it is safe to simply restart the svnserve Windows service? If not, then how to restart it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the service is THE way to do it if you want to avoid the risk of corruption. If correctly written the service (any service) should perform any required cleanup prior to terminating. Kill it any other way and you have no assurance of a clean shutdown.

Comment: Well, my question can be rephrased then like so "Is svnserve correctly written and thus handles the STOP event from the SCM correctly?"

Comment: @mark, while I can answer that with authority (I'm not one of its programmers, nor have I looked at the source code) I just can't imagine it not being correctly written to handle the various signals sent to services. From the programming perspective, it's so easy to do it correctly that it's quite unusual to see it done incorrectly.

Comment: I think I will take my chances, though we have only our common sense to encourage us.